# Update different textBox depending on filename in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, assign

I'm quite new to c# programming and I got myself a nice little problem now, and I would be very greatfull for some help.
I know that my example below isn't going to work, but it is just to give you an idea of what i'm trying to do.
The thing is that I want different textBoxes to be updated with the content of the file depending on the file name... So how do you assign textBox.text or textBox to something?

```
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, "Files");
   string fileName = e.Name;

   if (fileName.StartsWith("O1"))
     TextBox txtBox = textBoxNC1;
   if (fileName.StartsWith("O2"))
     TextBox txtBox = textBoxNC2;
   if (fileName.StartsWith("O3"))
     TextBox txtBox = textBoxNC3;
   if (fileName.StartsWith("O7"))
     TextBox txtBox = textBoxNC4;
   if (fileName.StartsWith("O0"))
     TextBox txtBox = textBoxNC5;

   StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(file);
   txtBox = rdr.ReadToEnd();
   rdr.Close();
}
```

Sincerely
Hjalmarsson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right lines.

You just make sure you declare the `TextBox` outside the if test assign the `Text` property:

```
TextBox txtBox;
if (fileName.StartsWith("O1")
{
    txtBox = textBoxNC1;
}
....

if (txtBox != null)
{
    txtBox.Text = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: This answers my question, and when I look at it its clear! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of different approach to elimate the ifs using generic Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> lookup = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();

lookup["O1"] = textBoxNC1;
lookup["O2"] = textBoxNC2;
lookup["O3"] = textBoxNC3;
lookup["O7"] = textBoxNC4;
lookup["O0"] = textBoxNC5;

var prefix = fileName.SubString(0, 2);

if (lookup.ContainsKey(prefix))
{
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
  {
    lookup[prefix].Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```